# How to save in a new column part of an existing string

Tags: python, text, split

In a dataframe I have a column which contains a list of emails. My manager wants me to keep the name after the `@` and before the `.` to a new column.
I tried the following:

```
DF['newcolumn'] = DF['email'].split("@")[2].split(".")[0]
```

but it did not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following with regex as delimiter:

```
df['email'].str.split('@|\.').str[-2]
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['sjones@abc.com',
                            'sletters@candy.com',
                            'kalberts@mail.questinc.com']})

df['email'].str.split('@|\.').str[-2]
```

Output:

```
0         abc
1       candy
2    questinc
Name: email, dtype: object
```